# npm install create-react-app not working on mac not as admin

Tags: reactjs, npm-install, create-react-app

On a mac in terminal I'm trying to install an run create-react-app & having some isssues such as it seems like it's not installing. I'm not an admin on the mac. Here is an image of the commands I'm running in terminal:
[image]

What could I do different to ensure it installs correctly? Any & all feedback is appreciated.

Comment: you can try using it with npx like: `npx create-react-app my-app`

Comment: Thanks CD still get "-bash: npx: command not found"

Comment: how did you install node?

Comment: also... if you want to run `create-react-app` as a global command, you need to install it globally. you're missing the `-g` flag, `npm install -g create-react-app`

Comment: I installed node by npm install; also if I try -g flag I cannot since i'm not admin on mac.

Comment: You can't run npm without having node installed already, and you don't need to be an admin to install stuff globally as long as your node installation isn't global, which it shouldn't be. I would uninstall node, then reinstall with https://github.com/creationix/nvm and get a newer version. npm is at 6 already